# How to create bar chart with background images

Tags: javascript, d3.js, google-visualization

Hi I want to create bar chart like image which i have posted, I was trying to do this using google api and d3.js but unable to achieve. I need a light background for bar after bar end to a fix height for each bar.please tell me which API i should use.

[image]

I have used google api

```
<html>
  <head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Ingredients', 'Quantity', { role: 'style' }, { role: 'annotation' }],
      ['28g',  28, 'red', 'Fat'],
      ['14g',  14,'red','Saturates'],
      ['9g',  9,'red','Sugar'],
      ['2.2g',  2.2,'red','Salt']
    ]);

    var options = {
            'legend': 'none',
            'title': 'per Product',  
            'titleTextStyle': {color: '#FF0000'},
            'hAxis': {title: 'in grams',  titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}},
             tooltip: {trigger: 'none'},
            enableInteractivity: 'False'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

    chart.draw(data, options);

  }

</script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

using this I got below 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to achieve that you can just plot another rectangle before the one you use to show the actual data, with the width as each bar and the height as the max value of the scale

Answer (score 0):

In the API
https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart#Methods

You have many options on backgroundColor.